# Get the text of dynamic radio button in android

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I'm trying to figure out how to get the text of selected dynamic created radio button on android. I'm stuck that need to ask help on stackoverflow community.

I want also it will toast the text when i press only the button.

Hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Thanks

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button btnPress1,btnPress2;

    String names[] = {"Braces Adjustment","Tooth Extraction","Cleaning"};
    RadioButton r1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPress1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPress1);
        btnPress2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPress2);

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        RadioGroup r = new RadioGroup(this);
        r.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams rl;

        //This is where i generate a dynamic radio button
        for(int i=0; i<names.length;i++){
            r1= new RadioButton(this);
            r1.setId(i + 1);
            r1.setText(names[i]);
            r1.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_radio_button);
            r1.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

            r1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            rl=new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            rl.setMargins(10,15,0,0);
            r.addView(r1,rl);
        }
        l.addView(r);

    }



@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btnPress1:
                //Toast here the text of radio button i selected but when i press the button
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"BUTTON1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.btnPress2:
                //Toast here the text of radio button i selected but when i press the button
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"BUTTON2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `RadioGroup r`  to `private RadioGroup r`. (you can put it under `Button btnPress1,btnPress2;`)

In `onClick() -> switch -> case`

```
int checkedRadioButtonId = r.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton radioButton = findViewById(checkedRadioButtonId);
String text = radioButton.getText();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Make your `RadioGroup` as a field:

```
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
```

In `onCreate` assign the RadioGroup which you have created:

```
radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
```

Get the selected radiobutton with:

```
// get the checked radiobutton id from the radio group
int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

// get the radiobutton
RadioButton radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
```

To get the text of the `RadioButton` call this:

```
radioButton.getText();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it